# Lodash return key if exists, otherwise return the other key

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let's say I want to do something like:

```
const result = 'someKey' in myVar
  ? myVar.someKey
  : myVar.anotherKey
```

I can achieve the same using `get(myVar, 'someKey', get(myVar, 'anotherKey'))`. I was wondering if there is another lodash method that looks cleaner than that?

Comment: If `'anotherKey'` is a plain one (you don't need Lodash to parse it using the `_.get` syntax), then you can just do `get(myVar, 'someKey', myVar.anotherKey)`

Comment: @VLAZ this is a simplified example - imagine this is more complicated. I want to know if there is a way to do complex lookup (i.e. `get(myVar, 'a.b.c', 'e.f.g')`)

Comment: OK, I see now. I don't know about "cleaner" but you can assemble a function from Lodash built-ins that does a series of lookups for you. Or even a custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No built in function in Lodash allows this (sadly). However, as [Alexander Nied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58493266/) said in his answer, you can easily create a custom function for this. I will use Lodash functionality instead of vanilla JavaScript just to demonstrate how it can work:

```js
function getFirst(item, paths) {
  const notFound = Symbol("not found");
  
  return _(paths)
    .map(path => _.get(item, path, notFound))
    .filter(result => result !== notFound)
    .first();
}

const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 42
    }
  },
  x: {
    y: 1
  },
  z: 2
};

console.log(getFirst(obj, ['g']));
console.log(getFirst(obj, ['g', 'h', 'z']));
console.log(getFirst(obj, ['g', 'h', 'a.b.c', 'z']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

[Chaining](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash) using Lodash is lazily evaluated, so the sequence is map first path to `_.get(item, path)` and if it fails returns a unique `notFound` value. Then if the `notFound` is discarded the next value would be mapped. This continues until either there is a match or all the members of `paths` are exhausted and the value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe such a lodash function exists, but a simple utility could be written to provide that behavior:

```
function getFirst(obj, ...paths) {
    for (const path of paths) {
        if (_.has(obj, path)) {
            return _.get(obj, path);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Just a slight note - `_.get(obj, path)` might return a falsy value even if the path exists. If that's undesirable (and it's possible it's fine), then you'd need extra handling but it should be easy to check with `_.has`